# Cannot access android.support.v4.view.KeyEventDispatcher.Component in Dynamic Feature

Tags: android

I am trying to extend an activity of Base module in a dynamic feature activity. 
It is throwing an exception Cannot access android.support.v4.view.KeyEventDispatcher.Component.
While if I extend a class from dynamic feature itself then its working fine. I am using the same support version by changing 'implementation' with 'api' in build.gradle of base app.

api "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure that your compileSdkVersion is 28 because of the support library should not use different version than the compileSdkVersion

and make sure the targeSdkVersion is 28 too

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved by migrating from support packages to androidx

Answer (score 1):

It seems a compile issue. Try to check **`File -> project structure ->project -> set Gradle version and Android plugn version,then rebuilding the project`**.

it works to me, good luck.